# Is there a way to play a system beep on Mac OS?

Tags: c++, audio, beep

Is there a way to play a system beep on Mac OS using C++ and Xcode? I understand that I need to use a library. Is there a library that works across both the Mac and Windows platforms?

Comment: Does `std::cout << "\007";` not work?

Comment: Does printing ascii value 07 work?

Comment: I think ASCII 7 (BEL) will only work for command line tools.

Comment: nah... Mac OS is supposed to be userfriendly. Besides, a piezzo beeper would be way too expensive.

Comment: Printing "\007" works. Please post as an answer and I'll select it. Just note that Xcode will not play the sound, but running the code outside of Xcode will.

Comment: [toot](http://github.com/vareille/toot) is a cross-platform C C++ file and command line tool that tries to call several sound generators to produce the beep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cross platform way to play a beep is `std::cout << "\007";`. I had been trying to play it by passing in a char and then decrementing until 7. That didn't work. Explicitly outputting the code did work though.

Answer (score 6):

I think you probably want to use [NSBeep](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/1473622-nsbeep/)

---

**NSBeep**

Plays the system beep.

```
#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>

void NSBeep (void);
```

---

This seems to work OK for a command line tool:

```
#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    cout << "Hello world !" << endl;
    NSBeep();
    sleep(1)
    return 0;
}

$ g++ -Wall -framework AppKit beep.cpp -o beep
$ ./beep
```

#### Update May 2021

While this solution worked in 2011, it seems that AppKit is now no longer C++-compatible, so you now need to treat the file as Objective-C++, i.e. rename beep.cpp to beep.mm.

Comment: In using C++ and not Foundation.

Comment: Do you mean you're just writing a command line tool rather than a proper Mac OS X application ? You can still use NSBeep() - see above example.

Comment: This doesn't compiles

Comment: @김선달: you're right - it ceratainly worked 10 years ago, when I wrote this answer, but evidently something got broken in the mean time. It doesn't look like you can use the AppKit framework with C++ any more.

Comment: @김선달: I found that you can still compile the above code as is, but for current versions of macOS and Xcode the source file needs to be treated as Objective-C++ rather than C++ (change .cpp extension to .mm).

Comment: @PaulR Thanks for the additional information. That's sad btw...

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate method which works on current macOS (Big Sur) in 2021 (unlike my earlier NSBeep solution, which now only works with Objective-C++, and not with vanilla C++). I disassembled `NSBeep` and found that it just calls `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound` with a parameter value 0x1000 (`kSystemSoundID_UserPreferredAlert`). `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound` is part of the AudioToolbpx framework, which fortunately still works with C++ (unlike AppKit).

```
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    cout << "Hello world !" << endl;
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_UserPreferredAlert);
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ g++ -Wall -framework AudioToolbox beep.cpp -o beep
$ ./beep
```